# Get gravity of View programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, gravity

I have some views in my app and I want to check what `gravity` do they have (**as a View class**).
Tried the implementation below but it gives me strange numbers like 8388659. I can't really understand what they are (center, right or back) and don't know how I can get gravities like that.

```
View editView;
...
if(Gravity.LEFT == editView.getForegroundGravity())
    mLeftGravityIv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
else if(Gravity.CENTER == editView.getForegroundGravity())
    mCenterGravityIv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
else
    mRightGravityIv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

Can I somehow get a View gravity as `Gravity.Center`, `Gravity.Right` and `Gravity.Left`?

Comment: Views do not have gravity. A `LayoutParams` that controls the view's size and position may have gravity, if that is a feature of that particular container class.

Comment: [`Gravity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity) is specified as a combination of integer flags. That "strange number" you got seems to be `Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP`.